# Creating a Connect 4 A.I

Tags: java

Right now I have a connect 4 game which is human VS Human, I control both the red counter and the black counter how do I set the black counter to A.I so it displays it by itself?

```
public boolean move(int cols){
    for (int rows = 0; rows <= 5;rows++){
        if (getMove(cols, rows) == WHITE){
            if (myTurn == true){
                count[cols][rows] = RED;            
            }else {
                count[cols][rows] = BLACK;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    my1Turn = !my1Turn;
    return true;
}
```

then I am simply using a on touch to display the counters How do I automate the black counter? NOTE this is not the actual code, just a concept

Answer (score 0):

Well, to automate the black counter, you'd need to write some procedure that intelligently picks a move for the AI player. Ideally, that procedure would produce the BEST move the black player could make. Let's call that procedure `makeBestMoveForBlack()`.

Then, you'd need to have your game identify when it was black's turn (which you're clearly doing through `my1Turn`) and instead of waiting for the player to make a move, it would call `makeBestMoveForBlack()`. Once the AI makes its move, it's the player's turn again.

NOTE: This is not actual code, just a concept.